# For loop if condition in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to store all values greater than 1 in a vector.  However, only the highest is stored.  See code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
y <- [0.02408371 0.48230110 0.43027578 1.14913520 1.50040601]

z <- c()

for(i in y){

    if(i>1){
    z[i]<-i
    }
}
```

Comment: `z = y[y > 1]`.

Comment: I think you just want `x <- y[y>1]`. No looping or if needed. You should probably start by googing an intro R tutorial. This is fairly basic stuff in R.

Comment: You're making a common beginner mistake of having your cake and eating it too with the loop index - you can either loop over values (like you are doing in this case, `for(i in y)` means `i` will be .02408371, then `.48230110`...) or loop over integers (if you used `for(i in 1:length(y))` `i` would be 1, then 2, then ...). You're trying to use `i` like both at the same time. `z[i] <- ` works well if `i` is an integer, `<- i` works as if `i` is a value. You need to pick one.

Comment: If you really, really want to use a loop, you could replace your assignment operation with something like

`z <- c(z, y[i])) `


But this is really slow. The problem is that your vector `z` was initialized to length 1